# How to put a before and after with tags in a wordpress entry?

Tags: php, tags

I'm trying to make two "before" and "after" buttons on each wordpress entry, but with related articles by tags. I have this code, but it doesn't work because it doesn't show me the related articles by tags

```
<?php if (strlen(get_previous_post()->post_title) > 0) { ?>
 <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_post_link('&laquo; %link') ?></div>
 <?php }?>
 <?php if (strlen(get_next_post()->post_title) > 0) { ?>
 <div class="alignright"><?php next_post_link('%link &laquo;') ?></div>
 <?php }?>
```

Any idea to put related pages (before and after) in each entry? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_adjacent_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post) to get the nexy/prev post by tag. I think this should work,

```
// get_adjacent_post( $in_same_term, $excluded_terms, $previous, $taxonomy )
$next_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', false, 'post_tag' );
$prev_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', true, 'post_tag' );

if ( $prev_post instanceof WP_Post ) {
  printf(
    '<div class="alignleft"><a href="%s">&laquo; %s</a></div>',
    esc_url( get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ) ),
    esc_html( $prev_post->post_title )
  );
}

if ( $next_post instanceof WP_Post ) {
  printf(
    '<div class="alignright"><a href="%s">%s &laquo;</a></div>',
    esc_url( get_permalink( $next_post->ID ) ),
    esc_html( $next_post->post_title )
  );
}
```